# Django: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: Name, id

Tags: python, django, django-models

Just get started with Django. I was following this tutorial:[Django Tutorial Part 3: Using models](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Models#re-run_the_database_migrations), and I encountered this issue at the linked step

- python3 manage.py makemigrations
- python3 manage.py migrate

After executing the second command the error appears.

Full Error message:

```
PS E:\DjangoDrill\locallibrary> python manage.py migrate       
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, catalog, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying catalog.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 356, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 132, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 1135, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_constraint(model, self.constraint)
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 562, in add_constraint
    super().add_constraint(model, constraint)
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 532, in add_constraint
    sql = constraint.create_sql(model, self)
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\constraints.py", line 239, in create_sql
    expressions = self._get_index_expressions(model, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\constraints.py", line 211, in _get_index_expressions
    return ExpressionList(*index_expressions).resolve_expression(
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\expressions.py", line 950, in resolve_expression
    c.source_expressions[pos] = arg.resolve_expression(
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\indexes.py", line 264, in resolve_expression
    resolve_root_expression = root_expression.resolve_expression(
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\expressions.py", line 950, in resolve_expression
    c.source_expressions[pos] = arg.resolve_expression(
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\expressions.py", line 829, in resolve_expression
    return query.resolve_ref(self.name, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1977, in resolve_ref
    join_info = self.setup_joins(
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1824, in setup_joins
    path, final_field, targets, rest = self.names_to_path(
  File "C:\Users\Narea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1725, in names_to_path
    raise FieldError(
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: Name, id
```

Here is my code

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db.models import UniqueConstraint
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
import uuid

class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, help_text="Enter a book genre")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('genre-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                Lower('name'),
                name='genre_name_case_insensitive_unique',
                violation_error_message = "Genre already exists (case insensitive match)"
            ),
        ]

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text="Brief the story of the book")
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=True, help_text='13 Character <a href="https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn''">ISBN number</a>')
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text="Genres for the book")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class BookInstance(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default= uuid.uuid4, help_text="Unique ID for this particular book across whole library")
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)
    imprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    due_back = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('m', 'Maintenance'),
        ('o', 'On loan'),
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=LOAN_STATUS,
        blank=True,
        default='m',
        help_text='Book availability',
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['due_back']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}({self.book.title})'

class Author(models.Model):
    """Model representing an author."""
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField('Died', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the URL to access a particular author instance."""
        return reverse('author-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return f'{self.last_name}, {self.first_name}'
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Author, Genre, Book, BookInstance#, Language

admin.site.register(Book)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Genre)
admin.site.register(BookInstance)
# admin.site.register(Language)
```

catalog migration 0001_initial:

```
# Generated by Django 4.2.11 on 2024-03-28 07:37

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import django.db.models.functions.text
import uuid


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Author',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('date_of_birth', models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('date_of_death', models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Died')),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ['last_name', 'first_name'],
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Book',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('summary', models.TextField(help_text='Brief the story of the book', max_length=1000)),
                ('isbn', models.CharField(help_text='13 Character <a href="https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn">ISBN number</a>', max_length=13, unique=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='BookInstance',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular book across whole library', primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('imprint', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('due_back', models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('status', models.CharField(blank=True, choices=[('m', 'Maintenance'), ('o', 'On loan'), ('a', 'Available'), ('r', 'Reserved')], default='m', help_text='Book availability', max_length=1)),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ['due_back'],
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Genre',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('Name', models.CharField(help_text='Enter a book genre', max_length=200, unique=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddConstraint(
            model_name='genre',
            constraint=models.UniqueConstraint(django.db.models.functions.text.Lower('name'), name='genre_name_case_insensitive_unique', violation_error_message='Genre already exists'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='bookinstance',
            name='book',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.RESTRICT, to='catalog.book'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='book',
            name='author',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.RESTRICT, to='catalog.author'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='book',
            name='genre',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(help_text='Genres for the book', to='catalog.genre'),
        ),
    ]
```

I have checked for some similar problems, but I did not found those solutions very related to my problem.

Comment: `Name` instead of `name`.

Comment: can you show us your catalog.0001 migration file?
Additionally, what type of database are you using? It might be some database specification.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I tried to replace all the name with Name besides two usages within Meta class. Not sure If I should replace those two. Now, the error becomes (catalog.Genre: (models.E012) 'constraints' refers to the nonexistent field 'name'.)

Comment: @Trantor: the ones in the constraints as well :P

Comment: @AskarMusaev I have added the file at the end. For the second question I have no clue. I was strictly following the tutorial as I am completely new to this

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Unfortunately, I got a new error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Name'

Comment: @Trantor: not the `name=...` parameter, but the `F('Name')`...

Comment: Delete the migration `0001_initial` and run `makemigrations` again. Some times mistakes in your code will get carried over into the migrations which will cause the migration to error, in this case it is fine to delete the migration and create it again. (You can edit the migration file manually if you want as well to fix it)

Comment: @Trantor as you see in your migration file you are creating your Genre model with 'Name' field. I assume that you are mistyped first time with capital letter for your model. You can replace the field name with 'name' in migration file. But it will be better to delete this file and run makemigration command one more time (which will fix other possible problems). Regardinig database question, you are using SQLite database (django default). You can check it part2, specifying the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no `Name` field in the model `Genre`, however there is a `name` field. `catalog migration 0001_initial` indicates this was not always so and it changed at some point.

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='Genre',
    fields=[
        ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ('Name', models.CharField(help_text='Enter a book genre', max_length=200, unique=True)),
    ],     ^
),         |- - Added initially
```

The simplest solution is a catastrophic database drop and restart. Of course this is unprofessional but if there’s nothing to save/fight for, why stress yourself?

There are a thousand and one solutions some of which I’ll work on and get back with test solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I deleted all the migrations and it worked. From all the comments I assume my mistake was changing filed name improperly. Therefore, how should I change the names during the process or should I decide at the beginning and never touch them?

Comment: You can change it in production. I haven’t had the time yet to bring any tested solutions but I’m heading there. I mentioned that complete deletion and a database drop is an unprofessional solution but the fastest at best.